# Is there a problem with the way I'm trying to display the table at the checkout page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this simple HTML shopping webpage and I'm trying to implement Local Storage and use it for the shopping cart. Everything is going through smoothly except for one thing i.e. my table on the checkout page isn't being displayed.
I'm attaching my code below.
I am trying to do this for my college mini project.
It would be great if you could spare some time and help me out.
Thank You.

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>My Shop</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">My Shop</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container">
  <h1>Iphone</h1>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="images/product1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="images/product2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="images/product3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Brand: </strong>Apple Iphone 12 max pro</p>
      <p><strong>Color: </strong>Pacific Blue</p>
      <p><strong>Memory Storage: </strong>512GB</p>
      <p><strong>Operating System: </strong>IOS 14</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>Rs.1,59,900/-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Brand: </strong>Apple Iphone 12</p>
      <p><strong>Color: </strong>Black</p>
      <p><strong>Memory Storage: </strong>256GB</p>
      <p><strong>Operating System: </strong>IOS 14</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>Rs.84,900/-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Brand: </strong>Apple Iphone 12 mini</p>
      <p><strong>Color: </strong>Blue</p>
      <p><strong>Memory Storage: </strong>256GB</p>
      <p><strong>Operating System: </strong>IOS 14</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>Rs.74,900/-</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button id="product1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whenClicked(this.id)">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button id="product2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whenClicked(this.id)">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button id="product3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whenClicked(this.id)">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <h1>Samsung</h1>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="images/product4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="images/product5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="images/product6.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Brand: </strong>Samsung S21 ultra 5G</p>
      <p><strong>Color: </strong>Phantom Silver</p>
      <p><strong>Memory Storage: </strong>512GB</p>
      <p><strong>Operating System: </strong>Android v10.0</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>Rs.1,39,999/-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Brand: </strong>Samsung Note 20 ultra 5G</p>
      <p><strong>Color: </strong>Mystic Bronze</p>
      <p><strong>Memory Storage: </strong>256GB</p>
      <p><strong>Operating System: </strong>Android v10.0</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>Rs.1,16,000/-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <p><strong>Brand: </strong>Samsung Z Fold2 5G</p>
      <p><strong>Color: </strong>Mystic Bronze</p>
      <p><strong>Memory Storage: </strong>256GB</p>
      <p><strong>Operating System: </strong>Android v10.0</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>Rs.1,89,999/-</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button id="product4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whenClicked(this.id)">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button id="product5" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whenClicked(this.id)">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button id="product6" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="whenClicked(this.id)">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-grid gap-2 tmargin">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="clearCart()">CLEAR CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="d-grid gap-2 tmargin">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='checkout.html'">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</button>
  </div>
</main><!-- /.container -->


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

checkout.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Checkout</title>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="bg-light" onload="getProductCountLocal()">
    
<div class="container">
  <main>
      <div class="row g-3">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
          <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
          <span class="badge bg-secondary rounded-pill">3</span>
        </h4>

        <table class="table table-striped" id="cart_table">
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </table>
        <small class="text-muted" id="total_price"></small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
        <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid first name is required.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid last name is required.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <label for="email" class="form-label">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$">
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter your shipping address.
              </div>
            </div>

          <hr class="my-4">

          <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>

          <div class="my-3">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input id="credit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked required>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="credit">Credit card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input id="debit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="debit">Debit card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input id="paypal" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="paypal">PayPal</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row gy-3">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="cc-name" class="form-label">Name on card</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-name" placeholder="" required>
              <small class="text-muted">Full name as displayed on card</small>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Name on card is required
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="cc-number" class="form-label">Credit card number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Credit card number is required
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="cc-expiration" class="form-label">Expiration</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-expiration" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Expiration date required
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="cc-cvv" class="form-label">CVV</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Security code required
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr class="my-4">

          <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getProductCountLocal(){
        //alert("Function called!");
        for(var i = 0 ; i < product_array_btn.length ; ++i){
          if(localStorage.getItem(product_array_btn[i]) == "true" && (!user_products.includes(product_array_btn[i]))){
            user_products.push(product_array_btn[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      var total_price = 0;
      var table = document.getElementById("cart_table");
      for( var i = 0 ; i < user_products.length ; ++i){
        var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = i+1
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = product_array[user_products[i]]
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = product_prices[user_products[i]]
        total_price = total_price + product_prices[user_products[i]]
      }
      document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = "Total=" + total_price;
    </script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
function whenClicked(ID){
  //alert("You clicked :" + ID);
  addToList(ID);
}

var product_array_btn = ["product1", "product2", "product3", "product4", "product5", "product6"];

product_array = {}
product_array["product1"] = "Iphone 12 max pro";
product_array["product2"] = "Iphone 12";
product_array["product3"] = "Iphone 12 mini";
product_array["product4"] = "Samsung S21 Ultra";
product_array["product5"] = "Samsung Note20 Ultra";
product_array["product6"] = "Samsung Z Fold2";

var product_prices = {};
product_prices["product1"] = 159900;
product_prices["product2"] = 84900;
product_prices["product3"] = 74900;
product_prices["product4"] = 139999;
product_prices["product5"] = 116000;
product_prices["product6"] = 189999;

var user_products = [];

function addToList(ID){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < product_array_btn.length ; ++i){
    if(product_array_btn[i].localeCompare(ID) == 0){
      console.log("user clicked:" + ID);
      alert("Product Added to Cart");
      //add to local storage
      localStorage.setItem(product_array_btn[i], "true");
    }
  }
}

function clearCart(){
  alert("Clearing all cart")
  localStorage.clear();
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 2);
}

// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

style.css

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.row img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.tmargin{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `checkout.html` page, The code snippet where you are setting data to the table is not executed after you push the data to user_products array. so wrapped the snippet in a function and called at the end of `getproductCountLocal()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function getProductCountLocal(){
        //alert("Function called!");
        for(var i = 0 ; i < product_array_btn.length ; ++i){
          if(localStorage.getItem(product_array_btn[i]) == "true" && (!user_products.includes(product_array_btn[i]))){
            user_products.push(product_array_btn[i]);
          }
        }
        setProduct();
      }
      function setProduct(){
        var total_price = 0;
        var table = document.getElementById("cart_table");
        for( var i = 0 ; i < user_products.length ; ++i){
          var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          cell1.innerHTML = i+1
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          cell2.innerHTML = product_array[user_products[i]]
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          cell3.innerHTML = product_prices[user_products[i]]
          total_price = total_price + product_prices[user_products[i]]
        }
        document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = "Total=" + total_price;
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank You for your help